# select sum() in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Let's say I need to know how much money I've earned in whole my life:
What would I do in SQL is something like this:

```
select sum(salary) from employee_salary where employee_id=1000;
```

Is there some simple way to do this in mongoDB via mongoid, rails?
Don't even think to propose me using map/reduce.

The easiest way I've found is:

```
db.employee_salary.group(
    { 
        cond: { "employee_id":1000 },
        reduce: function(obj,prev) { prev.sum += obj.salary; },
        initial: { sum: 0 }
    }
)[0].sum;
```

But it looks so awful...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this one:

```
Employee.where(id: 1000).sum(:salary)
```